# Which Continuous integration programs support a good workflow for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm a bit confused on how continuous integration works with a Windows Phone App.  Is there a way to upload the app to the marketplace automatically, or do you still need to do a manual update?

Do I need my own server for this, or are there hosted options?

And which program works best to test, build, and continuously integrate a windows phone 7 app?

Edit:  I'm using Atlassian Jira, but Bamboo seemed to only apply to Web apps, not apps that are deployed on devices.   I have no requirements, and no experience, and don't understand how CI even works with a non-Web based project.   However, I do want our code to be passing all it's tests before it's committed to SVN, and if there is a way to automatically push the latest stable build to our users, in an automated way, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marketplace submission is a manual process and there is currently no way to do this automatically.

There are various continuous integration processes and tools available. Whether you need a separate server to run it on or which program will be *"best"* for you will depend on your scenario, requirements, experience and preferences.

You can use any solution which supports Visual Studio 2010 as long as you can install the Windows Phone SDK on the same machine. Hosted solutions may or may not allow you to do this.

Comment: And _technically_ CI isn't supported as the SDK can't be installed on Windows Server (without modifications)

Comment: @RichardSzalay you can run a CI process on a VM running an OS other than Windows Server though

Comment: true, though its hardly the status quo or particularly desirable.

Comment: @RichardSzalay needs must when the tools require it. Also, if you install the tool components individually you'll see that only the emulator has issues with a server install. Leaving that out isn't usually an issue for a build machine.

Comment: How many different options are there for the Windows Phone? How many options allow you to run it on your own server, and how many options offer cloud hosting?  What possible requirements are there, and how many options are there for different levels of experience, or different scenarios?

From what I can find on the web, there isn't any option.  But you are implying there are too many options to choose from. Which one is it?

Comment: @MattLacey - Fair enough, though we automate our acceptance tests against the emulator (but manage to do so on WS with the setup mod)